# Replacement of org.hibernate.id.TableHiLoGenerator in Hibernate 5.2.2

Tags: hibernate

We have migrated from Hibernate 3.2 to Hibernate 5.2.2. We are getting the following exception while using (org.hibernate.id.TableHiLoGenerator)
In Hibernate 5.2.2 We need to know the replacement of org.hibernate.id.TableHiLoGenerator

Exception:
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not interpret id generator strategy [org.hibernate.id.TableHiLoGenerator]
    at org.hibernate.id.factory.internal.DefaultIdentifierGeneratorFactory.getIdentifierGeneratorClass(DefaultIdentifierGeneratorFactory.java:144)
    at org.hibernate.id.factory.internal.DefaultIdentifierGeneratorFactory.createIdentifierGenerator(DefaultIdentifierGeneratorFactory.java:115)

Comment: I too have this problem. Have you found the solution ?